# Which Tool to use for animations?

Tags: .net, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a concept of Virtual Mart for my Final year Project. This concept will implement the concept of virtual shopping in a way that If there is a shopping store in which there is a shelf containing all items related to Shampoo than on the **website** there will also be a shelf  which will have all items related to the shampoo and if the user wishes to buy the product and clicks on to it, the product will be added to cart then. I hope you people understand what i`m trying to deliver. 
**The question is I am stuck on to what tool do i use to do the animations?** I use Visual Studio as my IDE and platform i have chosen is .Net 4.0.. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [SilverSprite](http://silversprite.codeplex.com/) in Silverlight for doing this sort of online virtual environment and communicate the user actions with the backend website using WCF.

Comment: Hasan, can you please explain a bit more.. actually i`m newbie and has only worked on c# and asp.net. no idea of wcf and silversprite

Comment: @AbidAli then this is the chance to learn them. WCF is a communication framework between two apps and SilverSprite is for making games like animation.

Comment: i also discussed this project with someone else. they recommended to use Flash.. will Flash help me in this way?

Comment: You platform of choice was .NET so Silverlight is a better option if you're more comfortable with it. Flash; you'll have to learn from ground up. It is possible in both.

Comment: i cant find any help of SilverSprite by only just googling it. can you please provide me with some of the links and helps?

Comment: how do i configure SilverSprite Library in VS2010?

Answer (score 1):

Animiations can only run on the client via JavaScript. You can use different libraries.

- http://jquery.com/
- http://jqueryui.com/
- http://script.aculo.us/

Take a look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager to get a feeling what such an application could look like.